# VB.NET Create New Processes at request

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, process, undefined, createprocess

i have a problem to create undefined number of processes with a function..

```
Function CreateJobProcess(ByVal Name, ByVal ffmpegpath, ByVal params)
        Try
            Dim Job As New Process

            Job.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
            Job.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
            Job.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
            Job.StartInfo.FileName = ffmpegpath
            Job.StartInfo.Arguments = params
            Job.Start()

            Return Job.Handle

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Return Nothing

    End Function
```

that function is call from 1 up to several times depending on selected listview entries, so i need a different name for each process.

for each process i need to have:

1.name of the new process created (i have to read standard error from the process).
2.handle of the new process created.

P.S.

it's possible to get standard error from the handle of the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should turn on Option Strict to avoid certain kinds of bugs.

You dont really need a name, by which I take it to mean a variable, but you do want to retain the Process reference so you can dispose of it when it is done and to read StdErr and StdOut.

If you plan to process StdOut, you need to add a handler and then some code in the event to process it.  Do the same for StdErr using a handler for `ErrorDataReceived`

```
' a collection of the jobs
Private jobs As New List(Of Process)
```

Then your Job Creator could return the new process or store it in the list itself.

```
Private Sub CreateNewJob(ffmpegpath As String, params As String)
    Dim P As New Process
    With P.StartInfo
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .CreateNoWindow = False
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .FileName = ffmpegpath 
        .Arguments = params 
    End With

    AddHandler P.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf _OutputDataReceived
    jobs.Add(P)
    P.Start()

End Sub
```

I would add a Try/Catch in the creator and  construct it as a `Function` which returns the `Process` or `Nothing` if it failed for one reason or another.  As a function:

```
Dim p As Process = CreateNewJob("file path", "job args")
If p IsNot Nothing Then
    jobs.Add(p)
End If
```

You don't have a name, but `jobs(N)` provides a reference so you can `Dispose` of them once they are done (`jobs(N).HasExited = True`).  It provides an easy way to know how many of them you have running as well so that you do not start too many at one time.

The event handler for processing output:

```
Private Sub _OutputDataReceived(sender As Object, 
           e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
   ' e.Data will be the output from the child process
End Sub
```

Comment: I think it's done... Another question... Maybe i can use a dictionary to have a name reference